# Passing a variable into sp_helptext

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

We want to dynamically pass variables into sp_helptext but because sp_helptext accept a variable passed into the colon; this is causing an error.
My query looks like so:

```
   EXEC sp_helptext N'DatabaseName.dbo.SpName';   --- this works

   DECLARE @spName VARCHAR(120) = 'spName'

   EXEC sp_helptext N'DatabaseName.dbo.'+@spName+''
```

And the error:

```
   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 53
   Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that string operations are not supported for arguments.

This is easy enough to fix.  Just do the string operations before the call:

```
DECLARE @spName VARCHAR(120) = 'spName';
DECLARE @fullName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DatabaseName.dbo.' + @spName;

EXEC sp_helptext @fullName;
```

This is for demonstration.  If you are actually passing such values in, then you should be using [QUOTENAME()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Lovely!
Thank you